# Asp.net Core 2.0 Custom Cookie based authentication

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have upgraded from asp.net core 1.0 to asp.net core 2.0 I need url based authentication which create a authorized cookie. There is no Login page. 
If url contains certain token I need to authenticate the request if not redirect them to error page. I am stuck in redirect loop. what's wrong in my code

ConfigureServices method

```
 services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddCookie(options =>
                {
                    options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Error/");
                    options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Error/");
                    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
                    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);

                });
```

Configure Method

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.ValidateRequest(Configuration);
```

In validaterequest middleware

```
public Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
                context.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                   principal,
                   new AuthenticationProperties
                   {
                       ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(expiration),
                       IsPersistent = true,
                       AllowRefresh = true,
                       IssuedUtc = DateTime.UtcNow,
                   });
return _next.Invoke(context);
}


[MiddlewareFilter(typeof(validaterequestPipeline))]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
      [Authorize]
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
        }
   }
```

Comment: Reference [Using Cookie Authentication without ASP.NET Core Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?tabs=aspnetcore2x)

Comment: I based it on that but something is not working

Comment: Are you awaiting the sign in? You provided code does not show that. provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem, allowing a better understanding of what is being asked.

Comment: Ok with cookies there is at least 2 steps. You authenticate and then a cookie is passed back in the response. That cookie is then used on subsequent request. In your example you are trying to set the cookie and use it in the same request

Comment: Can you please give me an example?

Comment: For a start try awaiting the sign in first and see if that works.

Comment: Also based on your model I would suggest you look into JWT (Json Web Tokens)

Comment: I had this working in asp.net core 1.0 like this. Changing it to await on signinasync gives me same result, stuck in redirect loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Login was working properly on `http/localhost` but once it is on `https/subdomain.domain.com` it didn't work.
Change was to do this

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie(options =>
{
    options.LoginPath = new PathString("/account/signin");
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
});
```

> `options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;`